# JQuery select() is not working inside fabric canvas event

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

When some object in canvas selects I want to select input text. But it is not working.

```
canvas.on({
 'object:selected': function() {
     document.getElementById('text_input').select();
  }
});
```

Comment: As i can test it, it works as expected. So provide minimalistic sample to replicate your issue. EDIT: indeed, works only the first time if input wasn't already focused. UPDATE: delaying it a little seems to have fixed it for me: `setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('text_input').select();},0);`

Comment: Thank you very much! I have made like you wrote with `setTimeout` and it worked. You can put It as a answer.